# When I run python in vscode it opens a tab in my browser

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run python in VSCODE it opens a tab in my browser. Even if I do the simplest code.

For example, `print("hello world")`. The same happens when I run a html file. And the new tab say local host refused to connect.

I solved the html issue with open in default browser but I can't seem to fix the problem with the python code.

Sorry if how I phrased that sounded weird. What I have tried: deleting extensions that may open in code in browser.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing VSCode?

Comment: yes I have. But the issue still persists. Thank you!

Comment: Okay. Can you share which configuration it runs when you run/debug your python file?
(You can check your configurations in `Run > Open Configurations`

Comment: "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: sorry, I didn't know what to put. But now that I look, I suppose localhost:8080 may be the problem. But I'm not sure what to put in its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default configuration of launch.json file:

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: hi, I'm new to stack overflow. How do I accept the answer?